# How to let ListBox scroll smoothly

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, smoothing

There is a listbox with the following ItemContainerStyle, it's binding to the ViewModel class but when scroll the listbox its performance not smooth. I check this on the web, and I replaced the visualstackpanel with normal stackpanel in the listbox. Yes, it scrolls smoothly, but it freezes when the data is loading. Is there anything I can do?

```
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem" x:Key="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutBorder" BorderThickness="0.3,0.3,0.3,0.3" BorderBrush="LightCoral"  CornerRadius="10" Margin="0,0.2,0,0.2">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualTransition To="MouseOver" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.1" />
                                </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#1BA1E2"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Gray"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To=".5" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="#1BA1E2"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0.6"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="NameTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"  Value="#E09728"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RepostTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"  Value="#1BA1E2"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="CommentTextBlock" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"  Value="#1BA1E2"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FriendBorder" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"  Value="#1BA1E2"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="64" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="80" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="130" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="170"  />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="37" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="37" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="FriendBorder" BorderThickness="2" Margin="10,10,0,10" CornerRadius="5">
                                <Image Height="50" Width="50"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding ImageUrl, Mode=OneWay}" >
                                    <Image.Clip>
                                        <RectangleGeometry RadiusX="5" RadiusY="5" Rect="0, 0, 50, 50" />
                                    </Image.Clip>
                                </Image>
                            </Border>

                            <TextBlock x:Name="NameTextBlock" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,6,0,0" Text="{Binding ScreenName, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource NameTextBlockStyle}" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="DateTextBlock" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,6,0,0" Text="{Binding Date, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource MidelTextBlock}" />

                            <TextBlock x:Name="RepostTextBlock" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,6,0,0" Text="{Binding RepostNumb, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBlock}"/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="CommentTextBlock" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,6,0,0"  Text="{Binding CommentNumb, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource SmallTextBlock}" />
                            <TextBlock x:Name="SourceTextBlock" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Margin="0,3,0,0" Text="{Binding Source, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{StaticResource MidelTextBlock}" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="2" Width="440" Text="{Binding Content, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="0,5,0,2" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                            <Border Visibility="{Binding IsBusy}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="3" Background="Gray" Width="420" Padding="5" CornerRadius="15,18,30,10" BorderThickness="2, 3, 1, 0.5" BorderBrush="Chocolate">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="OriginalTextBlock" Width="400" Margin="0,2,0,5" Text="{Binding Original, Mode=OneWay}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                            </Border>
                            <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="4" Stretch="None" Margin="0,2,0,2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" >
                            </Image>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about pushing some of the work off into a thread, use Observable collections and try using Virtualized Lists in the UI to aid in the some of the speed issues.

This helped me a little.
http://blog.landdolphin.net/?p=78

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I watch Silverlight TV and found a good tip.

> **Never let any image downloads happening while scrolling** : Image
>   downloading on long Listboxes should
>   be controlled by the ScrollViewer
>   state and position to optimize the
>   network activity and also it would be
>   effective to download the images in a
>   queue based background thread system.
>   This will ensure scrolling performance
>   by downloading only the visible set of
>   images, that too only when the
>   scrolling activity stops.

Check [this](http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2011_05_01_archive.html) blog post.

Comment: I can't open the blog link you give me.

Comment: I does work. http://jobijoy.blogspot.com/2011_05_01_archive.html or http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/SilverlightTV/Silverlight-TV-72-Windows-Phone-Tips-for-Loading-Images

Comment: Yes, I agree.But i really want to know how to make the listboxitem templete simply.I tried Off the VisualStateManager, but its not work any better.

Answer (score 0):

Loading images off the UI thread will aid performance. An easy way to do this is with the [LowProfileImageLoader from David Anson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2010/09/02/keep-a-low-profile-lowprofileimageloader-helps-the-windows-phone-7-ui-thread-stay-responsive-by-loading-images-in-the-background.aspx).

[Peter Torr has created a LazyListBox](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ptorr/archive/2010/10/12/procrastination-ftw-lazylistbox-should-improve-your-scrolling-performance-and-responsiveness.aspx) which among other things uses a simplified template while scrolling. Definitely check this post out.

In looking at your template it seems massively complicated for a ListBoxItem. I'd strongly recommend reconsidering whether you could use a simpler template (maybe combining some of the text off the UI so that multiple fields can be bound at once) and/or reducing the amount of information you show for each item. Maybe moving some of the details to another page.

Comment: Thanks!,I try the least thing to display. All the text displayed is essential.And LowProfileImageLoader you post is really help me somehow. But the performance is still not so good.